# Travis CI failing with warning about -Xdoclint flag under old jdk

Tags: java, travis-ci

I've got a `.travis.yml` file that specifies some older JDK's (see below) because I've committed to supporting JDK 6 and want to know if I break the build by depending on something that's `@since 7` or later.

My `maven-javadoc-plugin` configuration uses some javadoc flags that are not supported on old javadoc.

Is there any way to get travis to use a modern javadoc even when using a jdk6 JAVA HOME or otherwise work around this?

I could try and conditionally pass `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` by inspecting `$TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION` in the `script` phase, but I'd rather not complicate my `.travis.yml` too much if there's a better way.

---

## .travis.yml

```
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk6
  - oraclejdk7
install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dgpg.skip=true -B -q
script: mvn verify -Dgpg.skip=true -B -q
```

and a POM that configures javadoc like

## POM

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <nohelp>true</nohelp>
      <show>public</show>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <doctitle>JSON Sanitizer</doctitle>
      <!-- The Javadoc that ships with JDK 8 is spammy.
           http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#BEJEFABE -->
      <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:-missing</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

## [Error in log](https://travis-ci.org/OWASP/json-sanitizer/jobs/106549482)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project json-sanitizer: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - invalid flag: -Xdoclint:-missing
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/home/travis/build/OWASP/json-sanitizer/target/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
The command "mvn verify -Dgpg.skip=true -B -q" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

The below works for me, but I'm not happy about this level of bash-fu.

The operable change is the `script: ...` line.

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
  - openjdk6
  - oraclejdk8
install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dgpg.skip=true -B -q
script: "mvn verify -Dgpg.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=$(echo $TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION | grep -q openjdk6 && echo -n true || echo -n false) -B -q"
```